# How can I link data from Numbers to a Pages document?

Tags: pages, numbers

I'd like to have all my client invoices in a Numbers document, including invoice number, service period, daily rates,... and generate a invoice from that with a template I have created in Pages. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What version of Numbers and Pages are you using?  A data merge would be possible with Applescript.  If you are exporting from Pages to PDF for distribution of your Invoice, you could easily do the same using your Numbers file.  Add a template in a new sheet and use INDEX or similar to populate it from the data in the original sheet.  If this is an acceptable idea, I'll be happy to explain further in a proper answer.